# How to get milliseconds passed since unix epoch in C without multiplying seconds by 1000?

Tags: c, winapi, time, unix-timestamp

The only thing I know is `time(NULL)`, but it return seconds since 1970.
It's fine to me to use WinApi functions if C doesn't have needed function.

I even found `GetLocalTime` WinApi function, but it return current date-time as struct...

The reason I don't want to multiply seconds by 1000 is because I inject my code into some program, and my code used to capture certain events from two sources, and I need to know their exact time, because if both events happened at same amount of seconds since 1970, but different amount of milliseconds, then for me they seems like happen in same time, and it's hard to determine what happened first (I doing events sorting later...)

Comment: exist [`RtlTimeToSecondsSince1970`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-rtltimetosecondssince1970) and [`RtlTimeToSecondsSince1980`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-rtltimetosecondssince1980) for convert time (from 1601) to seconds

Comment: @RbMm - Sorry, but I don't understand how it can help me to get milliseconds since 1970.

Comment: if want more exactly time - `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime` - it return by fact 8 byte integer. or can use relative (boot) time - `GetTickCount64` - milliseconds but since last boot

Comment: You can use clock, which starts at 0 when your program starts.

Comment: @stark - Thanks, but I prefer something I can turn into real time later, so I can measure time passed between certain events in human friendly time.

Comment: @RbMm - Thanks, with `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime` ans some tricks I was able to get milliseconds passed since 1970.

Comment: If all you need is to distinguish whether events happened at the same time, there's no need to limit yourself to any particular epoch. Time since system start is good enough, [GetTickCount64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-gettickcount64) returns that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Unix, you have (probably you'll get some of these apis also working in windows) `gettimeofday(2)`, which is BSD implementation of time, it is based on `struct timeval` which is a `struct` that has two fields, `tv_sec` (time in seconds since epoch, as given by `time(2)`) and `tv_usec` (time in µsec, as an integer, between `0` and `999999`)

This will suffice for your requirements, but today, it is common to use Posix' calls `clock_gettime(2)`, which allow you to select the type of time you want to get (wall clock time, cpu time, etc.)  `clock_gettime(2)` uses a similar `struct timespec` (this time it has `tv_sec` and `tv_nsec` ---nanosecond--- resolution)

No clock is warranted to get nanosecond resolution (but someones do), but at least you get up to the µsec level, which is more than you want)

In order to be able to give the time as milliseconds, you have just to multiply the `tv_sec` by `1000`, and then add the `tv_usec`(if using `gettimeofday()`) value divided by `1000`.  Or if you prefer to use `clock_gettime()`, you will add the `tv_sec` field multiplied by `1000`, and then add the `tv_nsec` field divided by `1000000`.

If you just need to compare which timestamp is earlier than other, you can just compare both `tv_sec` fields, and if they happen to be equal, then compare the `tv_usec` fields.  Every unix I know about (except SCO UNIX) do implement `gettimeofday()` to µsec resolution.

Answer (score 0):

This is WinApi way to determine milliseconds passed since 1970.
I made it since no one provide answer with native C way (maybe there is no native way at all)...

```
    SYSTEMTIME unix_epoch;
    unix_epoch.wYear = 1970;
    unix_epoch.wMonth = 1;
    unix_epoch.wDay = 1;
    unix_epoch.wDayOfWeek = 4;
    unix_epoch.wHour = 0;
    unix_epoch.wMilliseconds = 0;
    unix_epoch.wMinute = 0;
    unix_epoch.wSecond = 0;

    FILETIME curr_time_as_filetime;
    GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&curr_time_as_filetime);

    FILETIME unix_epoch_as_filetime;
    SystemTimeToFileTime(&unix_epoch, &unix_epoch_as_filetime);

    ULARGE_INTEGER curr_time_as_uint64;
    ULARGE_INTEGER unix_epoch_as_uint64;

    curr_time_as_uint64.HighPart = curr_time_as_filetime.dwHighDateTime;
    curr_time_as_uint64.LowPart = curr_time_as_filetime.dwLowDateTime;

    unix_epoch_as_uint64.HighPart = unix_epoch_as_filetime.dwHighDateTime;
    unix_epoch_as_uint64.LowPart = unix_epoch_as_filetime.dwLowDateTime;

    ULARGE_INTEGER milliseconds_since_1970;
    milliseconds_since_1970.QuadPart = (curr_time_as_uint64.QuadPart - unix_epoch_as_uint64.QuadPart) / 10000;
```

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to use clock() in combination with time(NULL) at start of program

```
start_time = time(NULL)

....

clock() + start_time * CLOCKS_PER_SEC
```

That would give you a better estimate and maybe exact enough for your needs?